# Link color to other color xml in Android

Tags: android, xml, hyperlink, colors

Can you link one color to another color in Android xml?

Something like this:

```
<color name="ring_enabled_color"><color name="ring_disabled_color"/></color>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can you link one color to another color in Android xml?

yes you can, using `@color/color_name`. E.g.

```
<color name="ring_enabled_color">@color/ring_disabled_color</color>
```

Comment: no you can't concatenate strings. You can reference strings tough, the same way I showed you for colors or you can have one or more place holder(s) and concatenate it at runtime (programmatically)